# Change settings for xfce4-power-manager by script

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, xfce4-power-manager

In any case, I have to use Lubuntu 18.4.
I need to change some settings for the ‚xfce4-power-manager‘ by script.

Where does ‚xfce4-power-manager‘ store its settings file on ubuntu 18.4. ,
or is there any other solution to change power settings by script ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: I'm tired of any advice that doesn't relate to the question. Im using 18.4 as a frozen System only to use one single programm in full screen mode. The OS will be used in something like kiosk mode and will never be updated. The user have no right to do anything on that machine except that single programm. But thank you for giving feedback to topics that are not asked for here.